# MongoClient.connect to TLS server fails (ssl=prefer)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl

I'm following the documentation http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/tutorials/connect/ssl to connect to various MongoDB servers. Some are TLS some are non-TLS. Therefore, I specify "ssl=prefer" in the connect string.

```
var clientConnectOptions = {
  server: {
  sslValidate: false,
  checkServerIdentity: false
},
bufferMaxEntries: 0
}

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://server:port/test?ssl=prefer', clientConnectOptions, function (err, db) {
...
}
```

For non-TLS MongoDB servers, the connect succeeds, but for TLS servers, I get

```
2016-08-21T12:21:35.956+0200 I NETWORK  [conn2] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17189 The server is configured to only allow SSL connections
```

So the MongoClient does not seem to start TLS. The MongoClient error is just "closed".

What clientConnectOptions are missing?

Comment: as server require ssl connection so you have to provide proper certificate files as in documentation

Comment: I also tried to specify the PEM files without success.

Comment: But I found out, that the "ssl=prefer" does not seem to work. If I code "ssl=true", the TLS connection is established. For me the problem is solved, because now I will force TLS for all connections.